# ACF radio button not returning value within flexible content

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the [ACF plugin for WordPress](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

Using the Flexible Content field, admin can add a layout called "Copy".

Within this layout they can select the "Grid Type" (quarter, third, half, full). Here's how it looks within ACF:

[image: ACF Flexible Content]

And here's how it looks within my template file:

```
<?php
  // Begin layout builder
  if( have_rows('layout_builder') ):
  while ( have_rows('layout_builder') ) : the_row();
?>

  <?php

    // Begin layout - Copy
    if( get_row_layout() == 'copy' ):

    // Begin repeater
    if( have_rows('copy') ):

    // Grid
    echo '<div class="grid-wrap">';

    while ( have_rows('copy') ) : the_row();

  ?>

    <div class="<?php

      if ( get_sub_field('grid_type') == 'quarter' ) {
        echo 'quarter';
      }

      if ( get_sub_field('grid_type') == 'third' ) {
        echo 'third';
      }

      if ( get_sub_field('grid_type') == 'half' ) {
        echo 'half';
      }

      if ( get_sub_field('grid_type') == 'full' ) {
        echo 'full';
      }

    ?>">

      <?= get_sub_field('copy'); ?>

    </div>

  <?php
    // End repeater
    endwhile;

    // End grid
    echo '</div>';

    endif;

    // End layout
    endif;
  ?>

<?php // End layout builder
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

I'm expecting the `grid_type` field to spit out a class on the front end, but it's coming up empty.

When I test the field with `<?php var_dump( get_sub_field('grid_type') == 'half' ); ?>`, it returns `bool(false)`.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get subfield grid_type in wrong place, you have to do it outside of copy repeater loop. This should work:

```
<?php
  // Begin layout builder
  if( have_rows('layout_builder') ):
  while ( have_rows('layout_builder') ) : the_row();
?>

  <?php

    // Begin layout - Copy
    if( get_row_layout() == 'copy' ):


    $gridType = get_sub_field('grid_type');

    // Begin repeater
    if( have_rows('copy') ):

    // Grid
    echo '<div class="grid-wrap">';

    while ( have_rows('copy') ) : the_row();

  ?>

    <div class="<?php

      if ( $gridType == 'quarter' ) {
        echo 'quarter';
      }

      if ( $gridType == 'third' ) {
        echo 'third';
      }

      if ( $gridType == 'half' ) {
        echo 'half';
      }

      if (  $gridType == 'full' ) {
        echo 'full';
      }

    ?>">

      <?= get_sub_field('copy'); ?>

    </div>

  <?php
    // End repeater
    endwhile;

    // End grid
    echo '</div>';

    endif;

    // End layout
    endif;
  ?>

<?php // End layout builder
  endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

And I advice you to change name of repeater from something else than copy, as your layout has the same name.